# Google Cloud Pub/Sub retrieve message by ID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Problem: My use case is I want to publish thousends of messages to Google Cloud Pub/Sub with a 5min retention period but only retrieve specific messages by their ID - So a cloud function will retrieve one message by ID using the Nodejs SDK and all the untreated messages will be deleted by the retention policy. All the current examples mention are to handle random messages from the subscriber.

Is it possible to just pull 1 message by id or any other metadata and close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve individual messages by ID, no. It doesn't really fit into the expected use cases for Cloud Pub/Sub where the publishers and subscribers are meant to be decoupled, meaning the subscriber inherently doesn't know the message IDs prior to receiving the messages.

You may instead want to transmit the messages via whatever mechanism you are using to making the subscribers aware of the message IDs. Or, if you know at publish time which messages will ultimately need to be retrieved, you could add an attribute to the message to indicate this and use [filtering](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering).

Comment: ok. but is there another service in gcp that is better suited for my use case.
even cloud tasks is not a good fit

Comment: What you want sounds more like a database. Maybe Cloud Spanner aligns better with what you are looking for. You could potentially use Pub/Sub to send the IDs of the entities it should access in the database so it can be edge triggers or you could decide to just poll the database for the messages you want if you already know their IDs.